# Form will not post to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, post

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
    $dbhost = 'internal-db.s123';
    $dbuser = 'db123';
    $dbpass = 'technical';
    $db = "db123";
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
      die('Could not send your enquiry at this time please try again later.');
    }


    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['phone']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['password']);
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['firstname']);
    $surname = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['surname']);
    $country = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['country']);
    $nationality = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['nationality']);
    $dateofbirth = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['dateofbirth']);  
    $profession = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['profession']); 
    $membertype = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['membertype']); 
    $dateregistered = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['dateregistered']); 
    $agreedtoterms = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['agreedtoterms']); 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO members
           (phone, email, password, firstname, surname, country, nationality, dateofbirth, profession, membertype, dateregistered, agreedtoterms)
           VALUES('$phone', '$email', '$password', '$firstname','$surname','$country','$nationality','$dateofbirth','$profession','$membertype','$dateregistered', '$agreedtoterms',)";


    mysql_select_db($db);
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

        $emailTo = $email; //Put your own email address here
        $replyto = 'noreply@club.com';
        $subject = 'Welcome to the ';
        $body = "Name: $firstname $surname \n\nEmail: $email \n\nPhone Number: $phone \n\nCountry: $country \n\nWants a callback?: $callback \n\nMessage:\n $message";
            $headers = 'From:  Club <'.$replyto.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $replyto ;

            mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    echo "<div class=\"success\" >Thank you. Your registration is almost complete. Please check you emails for further instructions on how to complete your membership application and how to login.</div><br>";



    mysql_close($conn);


}

    else
    {
    ?>
       <form id="standardform" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
              <div class="dotted"></div>
              <div class="formlabel"> Phone:*</div>
               <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="phone">
              <div class="dotted"></div>
              <div class="formlabel"> Email:*</div>
              <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="email">
              <div class="dotted"></div>
              <div class="formlabel"> Password:*</div>
              <input class="inputstyle" type="password" name="password">
              <div class="dotted"></div>
              <div class="formlabel">Repeat Password:*</div>
              <input class="inputstyle" type="password" name="password2">
              <div class="dotted"></div>
              <div class="formlabel">First Name:*</div>
              <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="firstname">
              <div class="dotted"></div>
              <div class="formlabel">Surname:*</div>
              <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="surname">
              <div class="dotted"></div>
                       <div class="formlabel"> Country:*</div>
              <select class="selectstyle" name="country">
                <option value="">Please select…</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                <option value="Bosnia And Herzegovina">Bosnia And Herzegovina</option>
                <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                <option value="China">China</option>
                <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                <option value="Cote D&#39;Ivoire">Cote D&#39;Ivoire</option>
                <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                <option value="France">France</option>
                <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                <option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic Of">Iran, Islamic Republic Of</option>
                <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                <option value="Korea, Democratic People&#39;S Republic Of">Korea, Democratic People&#39;S Republic Of</option>
                <option value="Korea, Republic Of">Korea, Republic Of</option>
                <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
                <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
                <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
                <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
                <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                <option value="Serbia And Montenegro">Serbia And Montenegro</option>
                <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="USA">USA</option>
                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
                <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
              </select>
              <div class="dotted"></div>

              <div class="formlabel">Nationality:*</div>
              <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="nationality">
              <div class="dotted"></div>
                <div class="formlabel">Date of birth:*</div>
              <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="dateofbirth">
              <div class="dotted"></div>




          <div class="formlabel">Profession:*</div>
          <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="profession">
          <div class="dotted"></div>
            <div class="formlabel">Member type:*</div>
      <input name="membertype" type="radio" value="Investor" />Investor
          <input name="membertype" type="radio" value="Buyer" />Buyer
              <input name="membertype" type="radio" value="Seller" />Seller
                  <input name="membertype" type="radio" value="Developer" />Developer
          <div class="dotted"></div>
   <div class="formlabel">Date:</div>
          <input style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;" class="inputstyle" value="<?php $today = date("d.m.y");  echo $today;  ?>" type="text" name="dateregistered" readonly>
          <div class="dotted"></div>

<input name="agreedtoterms" id="agreed_terms" value="Y" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;&nbsp;I confirm I have read and agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>

                 <div class="dotted"></div>         

          <br />
         <button style="float:right;" name="add" id="add" type="submit">Submit</button>

        </form>
        <div class="formdisclaimer"> Any information that you provide to Club will be treated in accordance with our Privacy Policy.</div>
        <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not just enter this as questiontitle: "Hey, I'm new here. I've got 262 lines of code and it doesn't work. Can you debug it for me?"

Answer (score 1):

You've got a stray command at the end of the query:

```
... agreedtoterms',)";
                  ^--- here
```

which you'd have noticed if you'd had proper error checking on the query:

```
$result = mysql_query('...') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking return values of all the mysql functions.  This should actually give you some insight as to fact that your SQL is incorrect.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO members
           (phone, email, password, firstname, surname, country, nationality, dateofbirth, profession, membertype, dateregistered, agreedtoterms)
           VALUES('$phone', '$email', '$password', '$firstname','$surname','$country','$nationality','$dateofbirth','$profession','$membertype','$dateregistered', '$agreedtoterms',)";
```

You have an extra , at the end.

```
'$firstname','$surname','$country','$nationality','$dateofbirth','$profession','$membertype','$dateregistered', '$agreedtoterms')";
```

Answer (score 0):

While you're at it, how about changing this

```
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['phone']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['email']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['password']);
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['firstname']);
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['surname']);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['country']);
$nationality = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['nationality']);
$dateofbirth = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['dateofbirth']);  
$profession = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['profession']); 
$membertype = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['membertype']); 
$dateregistered = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['dateregistered']); 
$agreedtoterms = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['agreedtoterms']);
```

to this?

```
$fieldnames = array('phone','email','password','firstname','surname','country'
                    'nationality','dateofbirth','profession','membertype',
                    'dateregistered','agreedtoterms');

foreach ($fieldnames as $f) $$f = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST[$f]);
```

Comment: that's good approach but only partial one. He don't need these variables. It's SQL query what he actually needs.

Comment: True, it's the SQL query he needs, but he also uses these variables a little later on for the mail() call.  Unfortunately, the mail() is going to break because of they've all been mysql_real_escape_string-ed.

Comment: that's the point. So, mysql should be another concern aside from this one. Hint: a similar function using your array could be used to produce email body

Comment: Yup.  Agreed on all counts, and left as an exercise for the programmer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Suroot is correct.  As some advice you could use the sprintf() function when creating the $sql variable.
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_sprintf.asp

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO members
    (phone, email, password, firstname, surname, country, nationality, dateofbirth, profession, membertype, dateregistered, agreedtoterms)
    VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['phone']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['email']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['password']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['firstname']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['surname']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['country']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['nationality']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['dateofbirth']),  
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['profession']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['membertype']), 
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['dateregistered']),
mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['agreedtoterms']));
```

Comment: This is just removing the step of assigning each field to a variable first.  Whether you consider it an improvement or not is up to you.

Comment: If you're "improving", then you could also tell the OP to remove the `(string)` cast in the escape call - it's utterly irrelevant.